# dividing matrix into four sub-blocks

Tags: java

i want devide matrix  into four sub-blocks equally by vertically and horizontallty in java (Here, we suppose that m and nare even numbers) .

for example we have matrix:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6                  
7 8 9 1 2 8
1 2 3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7 8 9
1 4 7 2 5 8
3 6 9 7 2 5
```

I want to display the last block that is:

```
7 8 9
2 5 8
7 2 5
```

how i can resolve this problem in java.

Comment: Iterate over the right part of the matrix. What did you try so far? Please show us your efforts

Comment: how i can do this. can you help me?

Comment: All you need is 4 `for` loops. Begin with the top left corner.

Comment: I'm thinking a nested for loop where i and j start at n/2 or m/2. You should try to implement this yourself and come back with the problems you face and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Help us helping you by at least throwing in some code you did yourself. We will not code this for you.

Comment: thank for your answer, i will try coding and come back if i have a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the lower-right part of the matrix. Here is an example for a square matrix. I am sure you will be able to make it more generic for non-square quadrants or to get other quadrants than the lower-right one.

```
public int[][] getQuadrantOfSquareMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    int newDimension = matrix.length / 2;
    int[][] toReturn = new int[newDimension][newDimension];
    for (int i = 0; i < newDimension; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < newDimension; j++) {
            toReturn[i][j] = matrix[i + newDimension][j + newDimension];
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: You can’t assume that the matrix is square, only that both dimensions are even.